# how to Customize pagination phalcon?

Tags: pagination, phalcon

I want to Customize pagination phalcon,
and already read this tutorial

> [tutorial](https://phalcontip.com/discussion/37/how-to-pagination-for-multipage-component-in-phalcon)

but I very confused, how call helper in controller and view ??

and this Customize pagination I want
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU5KJ.jpg)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my services.php or Module.php (if multi-module) I have:

```
...
$loader = new Loader();

$loader->registerNamespaces(
    [  
        'Common\\Library' => SITE_ROOT . 'apps/common/library/',
    ]
);

$loader->register();
...
```

My Helpers.php file lives in SITE_ROOT . "/apps/common/library" and has a namespace of:

```
...
namespace Common\Library;

class Helpers {
...
```

Now in the controller I can use:

```
\Common\Library\Helpers::myStaticHelper(<my_vars>);
```